# Merging data into one column mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

good day i am building a website for recipes and im trying to display a recipe with multiple ingredients but the ingredients are in a separate table so when i run the query if i have three ingredients the recipe id will appear three times along with the other data because the ingredients column is populated by only one entry...is there anyway to merge these entries?

here is my code and link to an image of how the data is appearing..any help would be great

[img]http://forums.trinituner.com/upload/data/62/all recipes duplicate.jpg[/img]

my code

```
         $db=mysql_select_db("tasteofhome");



        $query = "select RECIPES.recipe_ID,RECIPES.recipe_name,RECIPES.recipe_author,RECIPES.cook_time,RECIPES.stages_description, INGREDIENTS.ingredients_name, USERS.user_name from
        RECIPES,USERS,RECIPE_INGREDIENTS,INGREDIENTS where USERS.user_ID=RECIPES.user_ID AND
        RECIPES.recipe_ID = RECIPE_INGREDIENTS.recipe_ID
        AND RECIPE_INGREDIENTS.ingredients_ID = INGREDIENTS.ingredients_ID
        ";

        $result = mysql_query ($query);

if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}


        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
        { //begin of while loop
     ?>
        <tr>
          <td> <?php echo $rows [0]; ?>  </td>
          <td> <?php echo $rows [1]; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $rows [2]; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $rows [3]; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $rows [4]; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $rows [5]; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $rows [6]; ?> </td>

        </tr>

         <?php

        } //end of while loop


         ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the `recipes` and `users` tables with an aggregate query that uses [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to join the ingrediants to a coma-delimited string:

```
SELECT r.recipe_ID, 
       r.recipe_name,
       r.recipe_author,
       r.cook_time, 
       r.stages_description,
       gi.ingredients_names,
       u.user_name 
FROM   RECIPES r
JOIN   USERS u ON u.user_ID = r.user_ID
JOIN   (SELECT   ri.recipe_ID,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(i.ingredients_name) AS ingredients_names
        FROM     RECIPE_INGREDIENTS ri
        JOIN     INGREDIENTS i ON ri.ingredients_ID = i.ingredients_ID
        GROUP BY recipe_ID) gi ON gi.recipe_ID = r.recipe_ID
```

Comment: This work thanks but it shows the ingredients ids instead of names can you tell me what im doing wrong here. I want the recipeid, recipe name, author,cooktime, stages, ingredients and username in one table

Comment: $query = "select RECIPES.recipe_ID,RECIPES.recipe_name,RECIPES.recipe_author,RECIPES.cook_time,RECIPES.stages_description, INGREDIENTS.ingredients_names, USERS.user_name
from RECIPES JOIN USERS on USERS.user_ID = RECIPES.user_ID JOIN 
(Select RECIPE_INGREDIENTS.recipe_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(INGREDIENTS.ingredients_ID) AS ingredients_names
FROM RECIPE_INGREDIENTS
JOIN INGREDIENTS on RECIPE_INGREDIENTS.ingredients_ID = INGREDIENTS.ingredients_ID
GROUP by recipe_ID) INGREDIENTS on INGREDIENTS.recipe_ID = RECIPES.recipe_ID";

Comment: @IidsSunglassesTnt Your query has `GROUP_CONCAT(INGREDIENTS.ingredients_ID)` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT(INGREDIENTS.ingredients_name)`, as I suggested